# Backbone.js hidden fields on submit

Tags: html, backbone.js

I am in the process of integrating my custom shopping cart with a payment gateway(Paypal). 
I need to submit my items with the use of hidden fields, but when I submit the form the hidden fields seems to be missing. (According to the the payment gateway my cart is empty)

I know it might be a simple problem, but I've been going in circles for the last couple of hours.

The code that I generate the hidden fields with:

```
 <% for(i=0,l=products.length;i<l;++i) { p = products[i]; %>                        

          <input type="hidden" name= "item_name_"+<% i %>  value="beach ball">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">
 <% } %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's quite simple :)

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<%= i %>" value="beach ball" />
```

FYI:

```
<%  i %> evaluate
<%= i %> interpolate
<%- i %> escape
```

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy Petrychuk, don't know how I missed that.